# Add custom tab to all pages in MediaWiki

Tags: php, tabs, namespaces, mediawiki

I've got a MediaWiki site and I would like to add a tab with a very simple "read article" functionality (without any edit/comment options). I followed the manual and tried to create a namespace for it, but it still doesn't work.

The snippet from LocalSettings.php looks like this:

```
define("NS_ARTICLE", 500);
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_ARTICLE] = "Article";

$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_ARTICLE] = array( '' ); 
$wgNamespacesWithSubpages[NS_ARTICLE] = true;

$wgContentNamespaces[] = NS_ARTICLE;
```

I created new methods in Title.php:

```
public function getReadPage() {
    return Title::makeTitle( MWNamespace::getRead( NS_ARTICLE ), $this->getDBkey() );
}
```

In Namespace.php:

```
public static function getRead( $index ) {
    self::isMethodValidFor( $index, __METHOD__ );
    return self::isTalk( $index )
        ? $index
        : $index + 1;
}
```

And in SkinTemplate.php:

```
$readPage = $title->getReadPage();
$content_navigation['namespaces']['article']['class'] = 'selected';
$content_navigation['namespaces']['article']['text'] = 'Article';
$content_navigation['namespaces']['article']['href'] = $readPage;
$content_navigation['namespaces']['article']['primary'] = true;
$content_navigation['namespaces']['article']['context'] = 'subject';
```

The Tab appeared, but it links to ":Title" instead of "Article:Title". If I look for "Article:Title" page, the following message appears:

> There is currently no text in this page. You can search for this page title in other pages, search the related logs, or edit this page.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to create a namespace for this, why are you trying to do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't touch the MediaWiki sources or you'll have to redo the same thing each time you upgrade. Tab manipulation is doable with [hooks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks), e.g. [SkinTemplateNavigation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SkinTemplateNavigation).

Comment: A hint on how to use this hook would be good to have in your post.

Comment: The second link has an example.